# Why am i getting different output if I use "return"?

Tags: recursion, void

Why do I need to use **return** statement before recursively calling BubbleSort function?

without return statement : no output

```
void BubbleSort(int arr[], int n, int j)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return;

    if(j == n - 1)
    {
        BubbleSort(arr, n - 1, 0);
    }

    if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
    {
        swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]);
    }

    BubbleSort(arr, n, j + 1);
    return;
}
```

with return statement : gives the correct output

```
void BubbleSort(int arr[], int n, int j)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return;

    if(j == n - 1)
    {
        return BubbleSort(arr, n - 1, 0);
    }

    if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
    {
        swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]);
    }

    BubbleSort(arr, n, j + 1);
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you don't use return, when the latest recursive function returns you are letting your program go on with the execution and it is going to execute `BubbleSort(arr, n, j + 1)` positioned at the bottom of the function.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `return` keyword we are assure that the control of program will move to its caller.

```
BubbleSort(arr, n - 1, 0);
```

when you're executing this, without return keyword, it's calling self and the control is not returning to it's caller therefore rest of the code also executing and it does change the business which was not intended and you might getting some messy things to your result.

the following snippet might help you to understand it better:

```
if(j == n - 1)
{
    BubbleSort(arr, n - 1, 0);
    return; // returns to it caller.
}
```